# ¿Cómo recuperar los datos de una columna de registro de una hoja de Excel en otra hoja de Excel?

Tags: vba

Quiero recuperar los datos (números de matrícula) de una columna de registro de una hoja de Excel en otra hoja de Excel cuando las columnas de nombre son iguales.

Es por decir en la hoja "Convocation" hay

```
Matric Apellido Nombre Avión
12     Burrow   Irving F15     
42     Nelson   Howard A10
18     Krings   Jack   F18
```

Y en la hoja "RECAP" tenemos

```
Apellido Nombre ...
Nelson   Howard ...
Burrow   Irving ...   
Krings   Jack   ...
```

Y me gustaría

```
Apellido Nombre ... Matric
Nelson   Howard ... 42
Burrow   Irving ... 12  
Krings   Jack   ... 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Con diccionarios sería la forma más rápida y efectiva:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Matriculas As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Necesitas la libreria de Microsoft Scripting Runtime en Herramientas->Referencias

    'Almacenamos la hoja con todo en un array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Convocation")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
    End With

    'Asumimos que la matrícula está en la columna A y los apellidos B y C
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'si encontramos valores vacíos salimos del bucle
        If Not Matriculas.Exists(arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3)) Then 'comprobamos que no esté duplicado el combo de apellidos
            Matriculas.Add arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3), arr(i, 1) 'guardamos en el diccionario el combo de apellidos con su matrícula
        Else 'si la persona podría tener más de 1 matrícula entonces:
            Matriculas(arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3)) = Matriculas(arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3)) & ", " & arr(i, 1) 'añadimos las demás separadas por ", "
        End If
    Next i

    'Almacenamos la hoja con todo en un array
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RECAP")
        arr = .UsedRange.Value
        'Asumimos que los apellidos están en las columnas A y B, y la matrícula en la C
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'si encontramos valores vacíos salimos del bucle
            arr(i, 3) = Matriculas(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2)) 'aquí asignamos la matrícula almacenada en el diccionario según apellidos
        Next i
        .UsedRange.Value = arr 'devolvemos el array a la hoja
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Me parece mucho, pero cuando compilo tengo este error: Sub o Function undefined. He puesto el código en `Microsoft Excel Objects` que contiene todas las hojas, en particular en `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @ThePassenger debes meter el código en un módulo y asegurarte de que tienes activada la libreria de `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Comment: Hmm, lo puse en ThisWorkBook al principio. Pero ahora hay ambas y persiste el problema. El problema esta con `UBond`porque cuando lo quito no hay problema (pero no puedo hacer las buclas tampoco)

Comment: UBound devuelve el número del último indice del array (arr en este caso), y te devuelve las filas, es decir si en esa hoja hay datos hasta la fila 200, el `UBound(arr)` = 200

Comment: De acuerdo. Hay una otra manera de hacerlo ?

Comment: Puedes subir el archivo y lo pruebo? Aunque sea con datos inventados.